# PHP-like high level C utility library

Tags: php, c, port

I'm looking for a PHP-like high level C utility library.

I've found the following libraries:

- [APR = Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/)
- [GLib (part of the GTK+ project)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glib)
- [qlibc](http://www.qdecoder.org/wiki/qlibc)
- [iMatix' SFL = Standard Function Library](http://legacy.imatix.com/html/sfl/)
- [cbase](http://www.hyperrealm.com/main.php?s=cbase)

All of them looks good, but i'd like to know if there is a straight C port of some PHP functions.
My aim is to speedup development using already well-known functions prototypes.

Comment: Yeah its called PHP

Comment: Why would you be in the need for something like this?

Comment: I've found this project has my same aims, but it is still quite incomplete: (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xstdlib/)

Comment: If you want to program with rad tools and their idioms, C is not the language you should be using. There are no advantages to using it for this, and countless disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this [eXtended C Standard Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xstdlib/) is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

There are many libraries for all kinds of things. If you want something with functions exactly like PHP's, you could try to adapt the PHP source code to your needs. You can find the standard built-in functions in `ext/standard/*.c` in the source code directory.

(the result will likely be worthy of dr. Frankenstein's appreciation though)